# any workaround for 403 error? cloudscraper doesn't seem to work

Tags: web-scraping, http-status-code-403

get 403 error when trying to grab data and seems like cloudscraper is dead. any ideas?

trying this code -

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
}

s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://www.brownsfashion.com/api/listing'
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

or cloudscraper version

```
import cloudscraper

s = cfscrape.create_scraper()
url = 'https://www.brownsfashion.com/api/listing'
r = s.get(url)

print(r.text)
```

error message -

```
  This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.
```

Comment: Can you share the base url?

Comment: i'm looking to get data for the domain (i.e., both men and women), so https://www.brownsfashion.com/ but currently focused on https://www.brownsfashion.com/shopping/woman/clothing